# trying to understand this: bool variables are value types in C#

Tags: c#, reference, boolean, value-type

In C#, basic data types such as bool and long are value types. This means that if you declare a bool variable and assign it the value of another bool variable, you will have two separate bool values in memory.
Later, if you change the value of the original bool variable, the value of the second bool variable does notchange. These types are copied by value. (Token from profestional C# 5.0 Nagel, Christan, Glynn, Jay, Skinner, Morgan)

so if we have a class as following:

```
public class Tutorial()
{
   public bool param1;
}
```

and then in the main class we have following:

```
Tutorial x, y;
x = new Tutorial();
x.param1 = false;
y=x;
Console.WriteLine(y.param1);
y.param1 = true;  
Console.WriteLine (x.param1);
```

the result shows `false` then `true`
my question is shouldnt it print `false` `false`?? as mentioned in the text i paste at the beganing?

Comment: No because y is x (reference type)

Comment: here is a good explanation for you @moji http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/CSharp/Lesson02

Comment: `Tutorial` isn't a boolean, it's a custom class.  Your code sample doesn't reflect the description.

Comment: @MethodMan Thanks bro, i got the point now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> my question is shouldnt it print false false?? as mentioned in the
>   text i paste at the beganing?

No, because both `x` and `y` are reference types and they point to the same object. This is happening due to this assignment `y=x;`. So changing the value for the `param1` using `x` is equivalent to do this using `y`.

> "This means that if you declare a bool variable and assign it the
>   value of another bool variable, you will have two separate bool values
>   in memory"

```
bool x = true;
// We copy the value stored in x to the y
bool y = x;
// We change the x and the y doesn't change ! 
bool x = false;
// We verify the above with writing to the console
// the values of x and y
Console.WriteLine(x); // writes false to the console
Console.WriteLine(y); // writes true to the console.
```

Comment: yeah true, I know that its reference types but what doest following means: "This means that if you declare a bool variable and assign it the value of another bool variable, you will have two separate bool values in memory"??

Comment: @moji: Try the same test, but actually use *bool variables* instead of your custom `Tutorial` class.

Comment: @David Thanks bro i get it now :)

Answer (score 2):

If you look at

```
Tutorial x, y;
y=x;
```

Your class Tutorial is a reference type.  The assignment

```
y=x;
```

creates an alias, with y referring to the same instance of Tutorial as x does.  Whether bool is a value or reference type is irrelevant, as you are modifying param1 of the same Tutorial instance.

Comment: Thanks bro, i know this, but i tried to understand the text given by the book.

Comment: Sure thing.  Glad you got it now.

Answer (score 0):

No, because of this line:

```
y=x;
```

this means that y and x both point to the same object (an instance of `Tutorial`) so therefore any change you make to this instance via y will also be reflected when you reference the instance via x.

In this case, both x and y are references because `Tutorial`, being a class, is a reference type.

Answer (score 0):

This shows false, false:

```
public class Tutorial()
{
   public bool param1;
   public bool param2;
}

Tutorial x;
x = new Tutorial();
x.param1 = false;
x.param2=x.param1;
Console.WriteLine(x.param1);
x.param1 = true;  
Console.WriteLine (x.param2);
```